# Links being inserted into my content where I didn't place them

Tags: css, html

I put a link to the homepage on my header image but that link is coming up on all the buttons and headings and paragraphs that I have on my webpage. What gives? Please see my css and html, probably very easy.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Заголовок страницы</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href src="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
            </div>
                <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="current" href src="#">Home</li>
                    <li><a href src="#">About</li>
                    <li><a href src="#">Contact</li>
                    <li class="phone">Call Us: <span>416-514-0370</span></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="content">
        <h1>We are coming soon..</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(reset.css);
body {
    background: url(../images/background.png) repeat;

}

#wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo{
    width: 204px;
    height: 136px;
    float: left;
}

#menu{
    width: 960px;
    height: 70px;
    background: url(../images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
}

#menu ul {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul li{
    float: left;
    font: bold 18px Arial;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li span {
    color: #F51111;
}

#menu .current, #menu ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu .phone{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#content h1 {
    font: bold 55px Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed `</a>`

```
<li><a href src="#">About</a></li>
```

Comment: thank you bro I figured it out. I was missing a bunch of closing a tags but it's comforting to know someone can help me out so quick!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a bunch of closing  tags.